# Errors while passing parameters into a psql command

Tags: sql, bash, amazon-redshift, psql

I'm trying to connect to a Redshift cluster and run a SQL script with parameters, but am getting errors.

Here's the Bash command:

```
psql -v schema="$REDSHIFT_SCHEMA" -h "$REDSHIFT_HOSTNAME" -d "$REDSHIFT_DATABASE" -U "$REDSHIFT_USERNAME" -p "$REDSHIFT_PORT" -f "nulltest.sql" -v inputStartDateId=20170318 -v inputEndDateId=20170404
```

And the contents of `nulltest.sql` is:

```
select 
    COALESCE( $inputStartDateId, min(StartDateID)),
    COALESCE( $inputEndDateId, max(EndDateID))
from (
    select 
        row_number()over(order by FiscalWeekID desc) as rownum,
        FiscalWeekID,
        min(dateid)StartDateID
        ,max(dateid)EndDateID 
    from 
        dm.dim_Time
    where DateKey < getdate()
    group by FiscalWeekID
    ) a
where rownum <= 3
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
psql:nulltest.sql:15: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 2:  COALESCE( $inputStartDateId, max(StartDateID))
```

Am I calling the parameter incorrectly in the SQL script? The SQL runs perfectly fine through Aginity when I pass values into the parameter at run time. I'm not sure what's supposed to be different when calling the SQL through the `psql` command though

Comment: what's the difference between the top min/max and the inner one?

Comment: are you passing the dates to create a date range or something else

Comment: The inner one helps define and find the StarDateID and EndDateID. I'm passing the parameters in because sometimes I have to manually set the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing your parameters correctly on the command line, but your nulltest.sql file should use `:inputStartDateId` or `:'inputStartDateId'` instead of `$inputStartDateId`. Previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850125/6650678 .