# How to use timestamp column to get data between two dates?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a below query which gives me data for past X days. Instead of that I wanted to get data in between two dates which should be configurable if possible? Is there any way to do it?

```
SELECT processId,
 houroftheday,
 minuteofhour,
 listagg(clientId, ',') within group (order by minuteofhour) as clientIds,
 count(*) as psg
 FROM data.process
 where kite = 'BULLS'
 and code is null
 and timestampinepochsecond > date_part(epoch, sysdate) - X*24*60*60
 group by 1, 2, 3
```

`timestampinepochsecond` column has this value - 1599608655

How can I use `timestampinepochsecond` column to get data in between two dates? Something like below:

```
 timestampinepochsecond between 2020-12-01 AND 2021-01-05
```

**Update**

I am trying to declare two variables and use those in my query as shown below but it doesn't work-

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_variables AS SELECT 
   cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-09 16:22:17.897' ) as bigint) AS StartDate, 
   cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-10 16:22:17.897' ) as bigint)      AS EndDate,
   5556::BIGINT       AS some_id;

SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM tmp_variables;
```

Comment: WHERE t.timestamp_col >= '2020-12-01'
   AND t.timestamp_col <  '2021-01-05'

Comment: My `timestampinepochsecond` column has value like this - `1599608655` @MeghshyamSonar

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to convert date time to Epoch Timestamp and then query based on that:

```
    -- this will get the the timestamp in seconds
    DECLARE @startTimeStamp bigint = cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-09 16:22:17.897' ) as bigint)

 DECLARE @endTimeStamp bigint = cast(DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-12-10 16:22:17.897' ) as bigint)
    

-- then your query.

SELECT processId,
 houroftheday,
 minuteofhour,
 listagg(clientId, ',') within group (order by minuteofhour) as clientIds,
 count(*) as psg
 FROM data.process
 where kite = 'BULLS'
 and code is null
 and timestampinepochsecond >= @startTimeStamp  AND  timestampinepochsecond 
 < @endTimeStamp
 group by 1, 2, 3
```

if this is a stored procedure - you could pass in start date and end date is an parameters - then convert to Epoch Seconds.

Comment: Sorry I was away for a while. Looks like I cannot use `Declare variables` here and use then in select query. I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822176/declare-a-variable-in-redshift/40728524) as well. Is there any way I can do this in redshift? I would like to declare `startTimeStamp` and `endTimeStamp` at the top just like you have and use them in my select query below. Is this possible to do by any chance?

Comment: I updated in my question with what I have tried but it gives syntax error as obvious - Any thoughts what is wrong I am doing there?