# How to get six weeks data from a week column?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a legacy query in which I am looking data for six weeks as shown below. In my below AND condition I get data for past six weeks and it worked fine in `2020` middle and end. But since `2021` started, this stopped working because of obvious subtraction I am doing with 6.

```
AND data.week_col::integer BETWEEN DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE) - 6 AND DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE) - 1
```

There is a bug in above query because of which it stopped working in 2021. How can I change above condition so that it can work entire year without any issues and give me data for past 6 weeks.

**Update**

Below is my query which I am running:

```
select *,
dateadd(d, - datepart(dow, trunc(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','PST8PDT',client_date))), trunc(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','PST8PDT',client_date)) + 6) as day,
date_part(week, day) as week_col
from holder data
where data.week_col::integer BETWEEN DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE) - 6 AND DATE_PART(w, CURRENT_DATE) - 1
```

`client_date` column has values like this - `2021-01-15 21:30:00.0`. And from that I get value of `day` column and from `day` column I get value of
`week_col` column as shown above.

`week_col` column has values like `53`, `52` .... It's a week number in general.

Because of my `AND` condition I am getting data for week `1` only but technically I want data for `49`, `50`, `51`, `52`, `53` and `1` as it is past six weeks. Can I use `day` column here to get correct past six weeks?

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what `data.week` looks like.

Comment: We do not have a full picture to help you with your query. If the only column you have is week, the task is impossible. The reason it does not work anymore is that this year we are on week 3 and you you are basically selecting week between -3 and 2.
Shows us more of your code, table structure, etc.

Comment: Ok I updated it now with my query and details about few extra columns.

Comment: Do you have a calendar'esqe table in your database? Meaning a table that has a logical set of sequential dates with possible week number values.

Comment: @RossBush unfortunately no we don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Would this serve as a solution? I do not know much about the redshirt syntax but I read it supports dateadd(). If you are normalizing client_date to a time zone converted day with no time then why not simply use that in the comparison to the current date converted to the same time zone.

```
WHERE
    client_date BETWEEN
    DATEADD(WEEK,-6,trunc(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','PST8PDT',CURRENT_DATE)))
    AND
    DATEADD(WEEK,-1,trunc(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','PST8PDT',CURRENT_DATE)))
```

If the above logic works out then you may want to convert the -6 and -1 week to variables, if that is supported.

Solution 2

This is a bit more verbose but involves virtualizing a calender table and then joining your current date parameter into the calender data, for markers. Finally, you can join your data against the calender which has been normalized by weeks in time chronologically.

This is SQL Server syntax, however, I am certain it can be converted to RS.

```
DECLARE @D TABLE(client_date DATETIME)
INSERT @D VALUES
('11/20/2020'),('11/27/2020'),
('12/4/2020'),('12/11/2020'),('12/18/2020'),('12/25/2020'),
('01/8/2021'),('01/8/2021'),('1/15/2021'),('1/22/2021'),('1/29/2021')

DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '1/23/2021'
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01/01/2010'
DECLARE @NumberOfDays INT = 6000

;WITH R1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    R2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM R1 a, R1 b),
    R3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM R2 a, R2 b), 
    Tally(Number) AS (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM R3)
    
,WithTally AS   
(
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(DAY,T.Number,@StartDate)
    FROM Tally T
    WHERE T.Number < @NumberOfDays
)   
,Calendar AS
(
    SELECT
        CalendarDate,
        WeekIndex = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY  DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate), DATEPART(WEEK, CalendarDate))
    FROM
        WithTally                   
),
CalendarAlignedWithCurrentDateParamater AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
        Calendar
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT WeekIndexForToday=WeekIndex FROM Calendar WHERE Calendar.CalendarDate=@Date  ) AS X
)
SELECT 
    D.*,
    C.WeekIndex,
    C.WeekIndexForToday
FROM 
    CalendarAlignedWithCurrentDateParamater C
    INNER JOIN @D D ON D.client_date = C.CalendarDate
WHERE 
    C.WeekIndex BETWEEN C.WeekIndexForToday-6 AND C.WeekIndexForToday-1 
    
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it gives me less number of rows compared to hardcoding week like this in the same query `where data.week_in ('49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '1'). Any thoughts why it could be?
`

Comment: Could be the DATEADD() is not falling on a week boundary. The second solution I posted uses the actual week number to count back. That way you want fall "between weeks"

Comment: Redshift doesn't have concept of declaring variables so I am afraid this might not work for me. Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822176/declare-a-variable-in-redshift/40728524)

Comment: Well, you can hardcode the values. It is just a concept to create a temporary date table. If you are going to be running a lot of date-based reporting and/or processing then you can benefit from a Calendar table. Simply define a range of sequential days that works for your business needs and then populate it with anything date-related such as DayOfWeek, WeekOfYear, MonthOfYear, IsWeekend, IsHoliday, QuarterOfYear, etc., etc. It will make these types of queries so much easier to work with.